# Jmeter Error: Couldn't save test paln to file

Tags: jmeter, jmeter-4.0

I am getting below error message when going to save my test plan.

I added regular expression extractor and the listeners
[Error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9uRqJ.png). 
I am not allowing to save my test plan now.

Comment: Are you logged in as `chamini` or other user? Is your file has read only permissions?

Comment: Yes I logged in as mentioned user. Nope. I had both read , write permission. Issue was a space issue. I able to see that via jmeter log on console. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Looking into yellow exclamation sign at top right corner of JMeter GUI you have few more errors, if you click on that triangle - JMeter log file will open, most probably it will contain enough information to get to the bottom of the issue. JMeter also writes its log into a file, by default it's *jmeter.log* and it lives in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation. You can also [increase log verbosity](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-configure-jmeter-logging) to get more information regarding what JMeter is doing.

If you will not able to figure out the root cause yourself - update your question with the log file contents.

---

You can also try saving your script into a location which does not contain spaces or [non-ASCII](https://www.asciitable.com/) characters

Comment: Thank you so much Dmitri . I could able to find the issue as you mentioned. that error was shown due to a space issue. I could able to save it on another location.

Answer (score 0):

1. Go To Click On **Option**
2. Click On Look & Feel
3. Choose Windows
4. Ask For Restart JMeter Click On OK
   Check Again

[image]